# SMB/Samba shares accessible but not automatically listed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, network-shares, smb

I have many SMB/Samba shares defined on my local network: on a NAS, on a multimedia drive, on a Mac, on a Windows 10 Pro machine, on a Windows XP virtual machine, and on a Lubuntu 18.04 virtual machine (both virtual machines are bridged to the physical network).

The Mac can directly see all of these shares ("Shared" section in the Finder). VLC on both an iPhone and an Android tablet do see all the shares as well.

The Windows XP can see only the shares from the multimedia drive and from the Lubuntu machine.

The Windows 10 Pro machine can see **none** of them in the Explorer (Network section). Still, they are accessible in by typing the address `\\<machine_name>\<share_name>` (well except the Windows XP shares for some reason...). Network discovery is turned on in the settings. Why aren't the shares automatically listed? What should I do or try for that? I have browsed many links without finding a solution...

Comment: The Windows 10 Pro machine can see none of them in the Explorer   ...  Try mapping a folder ....   NET USE T: \\IPaddress\folder .

Comment: @John As I wrote, the share are accessible by typing the address ```\\<machine_name>\<share_name>``` (I mean, it works), so yes mapping them also works. The point is that I would like the shares to be directly visible without having to know beforehand their names...

Comment: Windows 10 Browsing is not always reliable (transition away from SMBv1 and not longer part of Windows 11).  So mapping is probably the best way.

Comment: so for the XP box, XP (and some linux devices) only support SMB v1, which is no longer allowed for most modern systems. consider that a separate question (but one for which there may not be a good solution).

Comment: Try to enable SMBv1 on Windows 10 in "Turn Windows features on or off".

Comment: Enabling SMBv1 is a security hazard. Map folders instead.

Comment: OK, I understand that what I want is a feature of SMB v1, and that SMB v1 is disabled by default in Windows 10. Enabling SMB v1 wouldn't be a problem on this network, as the Windows 10 machine does not contain sensitive data. I can also live with mapping the shares instead.